Font Path is invalid in font-face
I need to use specific Font in ASP.NET Core MVC Project, So, in css file:
CSS:
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url(css/Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf);
}

But I get error that the font path is invalid
I tried to change it like:
 url(~/Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf);

or
 url(https://localhost:7267/css/Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf);

or
 url(../css/Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf);

But always I get the same error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()


Would I know please why my post is downvoted, to avoid this in my coming posts?
or How could I know the reason of post downvote?

Firstly you need confirm the following things:

Ensure that your font file (Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf) is located in the wwwroot/css folder.


Ensure your Startup.cs or Program.cs (for .NET 6/7/8) is configured to serve static files:
 app.UseStaticFiles();  //be sure the middleware order

 app.UseRouting();  
 app.UseAuthorization();    
 app.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

 app.Run();



Then, the wwwroot folder is the root for static files, the path should be relative to it by using /css/Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf:
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url(/css/Custom-VariableFont_slnt.ttf);
}

